# Do these functions have the same order of growth?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, computational-complexity

I have a list of functions and was confused whether they have the same order of growth.

$$f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$$

Given functions: $\log^2 n, \log(n^2) $

My method: I took the logs of both functions and got an alternative form. which resulted in the following:

$\log((\log n)^2) \longrightarrow \log (2 \log n)$
and

$\log(\log (n^2))  \longrightarrow 2 \log \log n$

And through this was able to conclude that $  f (n) = \Theta(g(n))$
Is this true?

Comment: By that logic n and n^2 are also same growth rate

Comment: For $ n>1$,we have $(\log^2 n)/(\log n^2)=(\log n)(\log n)/(2 \log  n)=(\log  n)/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\log(ab) = \log(a)+ \log(b)$